Cygwin SSH service rejects local user connection attempt
I've set up Cygwin on a Windows machine, with the OpenSSH server sshd as a Windows service, up and running. I used ssh-host-config -y; and in /etc/sshd_config I've uncommented: PubkeyAuthentication Yes.
On the client side - I'm starting off with what should be the simplest thing - the same machine, in Cygwin. The user is a Windows domain user, so let's call him MyDom\JoeUser. Some more info:
MyDom+JoeUser@mymachine ~
$ ls -lad .ssh/*
-rw------- 1 MyDom+JoeUser MyDom+JoeUser 4971 Dec  3 15:40 .ssh/authorized_keys
-rw------- 1 MyDom+JoeUser MyDom+JoeUser  525 Dec  3 13:56 .ssh/id_ecdsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 MyDom+JoeUser MyDom+JoeUser  187 Dec  3 13:56 .ssh/id_ecdsa.pub
-rw------- 1 MyDom+JoeUser MyDom+JoeUser 1675 Dec  3 13:57 .ssh/id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 MyDom+JoeUser MyDom+JoeUser  401 Dec  3 13:57 .ssh/id_rsa.pub
-rw------- 1 MyDom+JoeUser MyDom+JoeUser   91 Dec  3 13:52 .ssh/known_hosts

and I made sure the authorized_keys has the line in id_rsa.pub. Now, when I try to connect, this happens (snipped some less-interesting lines:
$ ssh -v localhost
OpenSSH_9.9p1, OpenSSL 3.0.15 3 Sep 2024
--- snip ---
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/JoeUser/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:redacted
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/JoeUser/.ssh/id_ecdsa ECDSA SHA256:redacted
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/JoeUser/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/JoeUser/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/JoeUser/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/JoeUser/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Offering public key: /home/JoeUser/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:redacted
Connection closed by ::1 port 22

and if I try connecting using just my plain username:
$ ssh -v JoeUser@localhost
OpenSSH_9.9p1, OpenSSL 3.0.15 3 Sep 2024
--- snip ---
debug1: kex_ext_info_client_parse: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256>
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/JoeUser/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:redacted
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/JoeUser/.ssh/id_ecdsa ECDSA SHA256:redacted
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/JoeUser/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/JoeUser/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/JoeUser/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/JoeUser/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Offering public key: /home/JoeUser/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:redacted
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Offering public key: /home/JoeUser/.ssh/id_ecdsa ECDSA SHA256:redacted
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /home/JoeUser/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /home/JoeUser/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /home/JoeUser/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /home/JoeUser/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: password
JoeUser@localhost's password:

... but the password is not accepted.
As far as the server log goes, this is what I get:
Dec  3 16:12:21 mymachine sshd-session: PID 2620: fatal: seteuid 4096: Function not implemented
Dec  3 16:13:39 mymachine sshd-session: PID 2623: Invalid user JoeUser from ::1 port 55645
Dec  3 16:14:45 mymachine sshd-session: PID 2623: Connection closed by invalid user JoeUser ::1 port 55645 [preauth]

My questions:

What user should I connect as?
What must I do to make cygsshd accept my attempt to connect?
Why am I getting these errors instead of the authentication just succeeding?

